# How to keep entered input values after Refresh

Tags: visualforce

Problem: whenever user enters the details and he clicks on clone button.entered value has to be available in after refresh also.Here after refresh automatically enterd account name & end date field becomes null..After Refresh also How can I keep my entered values???

```
  <script>
function setHidden()
{

    var hiddenRep = document.getElementById('j_id0:f:hdnRep2');
    hiddenRep.value = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var hiddenRep1 = document.getElementById('j_id0:f:accId1');
    hiddenRep1.value = document.getElementById('accId').value;
    return false;
}
```

```
                             <apex:commandButton value="Clone" id="cloneButton" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="setHidden();"  action="{!CloneSQ}" reRender="">
                        </apex:commandButton> 
                            <apex:commandButton status="statusId" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" immediate="true" />
                            <apex:actionStatus id="statusId" onstart="showLoading();" onstop="hideLoading();">
                                <apex:facet name="start">   
                                    <apex:image value="/img/loading.gif" />                 
                                </apex:facet>
                            </apex:actionStatus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br></br>

                    <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2">
                       <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel1"> 
                            <div class="slds-form-element" >
                                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-01">*Select Existing Account</label>
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-input__icon">
                                        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR ($Resource.SLDSv221, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search')}"></use>
                                    </svg>                              
                                    <input id="account_name"  style="width: 100%;" value="{!acctName}"  class="slds-input" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-activedescendant="" onkeyup="keyupAccountName()"/>
                                    <input class="slds-input" 
                                           id="accId" name="accId" value="" type="hidden"/>
                                    <apex:inputHidden id="accId1" value="{!accId}" />  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        <div class="slds-lookup__menu" role="listbox" id="account_name_lookup" style="display:none; width:20%; padding-left:0px;  ">
                            <div class="slds-lookup__item">
                                <button class="slds-button">
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon--small">
                                        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR ($Resource.SLDSv221, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search')}"></use>
                                    </svg>&quot;<span id="account_keyword"></span>&quot; in Accounts</button>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="slds-lookup__list1" role="presentation" id="account_names">                                                                                       
                            </ul>                           
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-lookup__menu" role="listbox" id="account_name_lookup" style="display:none; width:20%; padding-left:0px;  ">
                            <div class="slds-lookup__item">
                                <button class="slds-button">
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon--small">
                                        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR ($Resource.SLDSv221, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search')}"></use>
                                    </svg>&quot;<span id="account_keyword"></span>&quot; in Accounts</button>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="slds-lookup__list1" role="presentation" id="account_names">                                                                                       
                            </ul>                           
                        </div>
                        <br></br>
```

```
 <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label class="slds-form-element__label">*ESD Date</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right dateDiv2">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-input__icon slds-icon-text-default">
                                <use href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDSv221, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#event')}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <input id="date" class="slds-input dateClass" type="text"  placeholder="" label="Date Picker Label" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <apex:inputHidden id="hdnRep2" value="{!startdate}"/>
```

Controller Side

//This method saves Opportunity Record and redirect to Opportunity Page

```
 public PageReference CloneSQ(){

     if( accId==null || accId==''){
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'<b style="color:red"> Please fill the Account Name!! <b>'));
         return null;
      }
   //Converting data to string 
    string  dt=string.valueOf(startDate);
    //Checking the value
    if(dt==null || dt==''){

         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'<b style="color:red"> Please fill the Date field!!<b>'));
         return null;
     }


 try{
     PageReference pageRef;
    cloneAccountId = accId;
    esdDate =  date.parse(startDate);
     //AccountId Validation
     System.debug('AA cloneAccountId=============>' + cloneAccountId );
    cloneUser = pUsers;
    Id sqId = oSQ.Id;   
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    string fieldsNames='';   
    system.debug('clone user ::::::'+cloneUser);
    if(cloneAccountId != null && cloneUser != null) {
        newOpp = new Opportunity();
        system.debug('name');
        newOpp.Name = pOpportunity;
        system.debug('account id');
        newOpp.AccountId = cloneAccountId;
        system.debug('stage');
        newOpp.StageName = oppStage;
        system.debug('close date');
        newOpp.CloseDate =  date.parse(startDate); 
        newOpp.Markets__c = pMarkets; 
        system.debug('hii');
        insert newOpp;
        system.debug('hello');
        string id=newOpp.Id;
        system.debug('id value @@@'+id);
        id idval=id;
        pageRef = new PageReference('/'+id);
        system.debug('page ref');
        return pageRef;
    } 
    }
    catch(exception e){

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, never use things like:

```
document.getElementById('j_id0:f:hdnRep2');
```

The Salesforce-generated IDs aren't designed to be used in this way, and could change at any time.

To try and answer your question, the best way to retain any inputted values on a Visualforce page is by binding your screen inputs to a controller variable:

controller variable:

```
public String myVar {get; set;}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:input value={!myVar}/>
```

My concern is that you've pasted the body of a standard UI lightning page.

The standard clone functionality should bring previous value through by default. I am not aware of the clone button even being visible in "Edit" mode, so the values should be persisted at the point of cloning.

In short:
* if using a VF page, bind the things together
* if using standard UI, clone should bring existing values through by default
* if neither of the above apply, then I don't have enough info to answer your question, but am not currently allowed to ask any more questions